# Force container to stay in exact positions

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so the container on this page http://s72956.gridserver.com/dev/toggle.html# will always stay at a certain width no matter how you resize the page is there any easy way of doing this.

Comment: Which container are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a width of a block element explicitly, it will stay at that width.

```
<div style="width:300px">
   ...
</div>
```

Will remain 300 pixels wide not matter what. You might however want to specify the width in css rather an inline like I did here.

Comment: even with that it still moves.